# How to watch logs from windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I watch logs from windows phone 8.1. (for instance like for Android by using SDK, or for iOs by using xCode)

Comment: How about the Output window in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio Output Windows is handy if you are debugging your app but you cannot see/collect the logs in another moment.

I recommend the use of MetroLog, a lightweight logging system designed specifically for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps.

You can install it using NuGet

```
Install-Package MetroLog
```

Here's an quick example:

```
using MetroLog;
using MetroLog.Targets;

LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, new FileStreamingTarget());

ILogger log = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<MainPage>();

log.Trace("This is a trace message.");
```

You can find a tutorial explaining how to add it on your project at http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/11/adicionando-logs-em-universal-apps. Also there is an explanation regarding retrieving these logs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks for the tip ;)